# Batch-create Mapbox tilesets

Tags: mapbox, batch, tippecanoe

I'm trying to put together a command on tippecanoe that will batch-create tilesets that upload as individual layers. All of the layers are keyed to the same spatial boundary, which is in a geojson along with the unique fields for the individual layers. Right now I'm uploading them individually which is taking a long time and I have quite a few layers to create.

Is there a particular command input that I'm missing for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a shell script to run multiple scripts.

```
#!/bin/sh

tippecanoe ...
tippecanoe ...

mapbox upload ...
mapbox upload ...
```

`mapbox upload` is from https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-cli-py